# If java Serializable disappears, will the same be done with Externalizable?

Tags: java

I know the title question sounds like asking someone to look in his crystal ball, but ...

Recently learned that Oracle plans or considers to abandon the Serializable interface.  The reasons may be a lot like the reasons why I never was a great fan, and consequently haven't used it that much if at all.  I do like the "customized serializable" counterpart Externalizable a lot more though and use it relatively often.  Can any of the close Java watchers tell whether the plans also include abandoning Externalizable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can relax.  JEP 154 that proposed the removal of Serialization has been withdrawn.

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046144

But that is not the end of the story.  According to [this article](https://adtmag.com/articles/2018/05/30/java-serialization.aspx), the removal of serialization is a "long term goal" for the Java language team.   And in the [Project Amber](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/) pages, there is a document by Brian Goetz entitled ["Towards Better Serialization"](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/serialization.html) which details the problems of the current Serialization model and implementation, and proposes a new model in which persistence gets explicit support in the language itself.

Note that this is a position paper rather than a JEP.  So it is likely to be a few years before this happens, if it happens at all.  (And it is way too early to answer questions about what will happen to the current mechanisms.  Brian Goetz's paper says nothing about that.)

Comment: I see.  Answers can hardly get any more final than that :-)